# Differentiating with respect to $1 - x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am fairly sure this is a silly question, but a Google search was insufficient to find a satisfactory answer.

If I differentiate some function of $x$ with respect to $1-x$, what do I get compared to differentiating with respect to $x$?

I know I need to use the chain rule to figure this out, but I am stuck on the details.

Comment: What does it mean to differentiate with respect to $1-x$???

Comment: @copper.hat I guess he considers $f(g(x))$ and wants to calculate $f^\prime(g(x))$

Comment: @Thomas: I was hoping the OP might express what they want a little more clearly.

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe it doesn't even make sense to do that. I was thinking that if I had some function of x, I could let u = 1 - x, and take the derivative with respect to u.  The purpose of my question is that I learned that the deposit multiplier is the derivative of deposit size with respect to the reserve requirement. But my expression is MUCH easier to differentiate with respect to u = (1 - rr), if that is a thing I can do.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean $\frac{dy}{d(1-x)}$, that is
$$\frac{dy}{d(1-x)} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{d(1-x)} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{d(1-x)}{dx}} = -\frac{dy}{dx}$$
because $\frac{d(1-x)}{dx} = -1$.

Comment: That is gross. ${}$

Comment: What a totally not mathematical proof! Didn't know we were in fact at Physics StackExchange

Comment: The proof is just fine. True, it uses that little trick there in the second expression, which gives some budding mathematicians the chills...but what the heck! That's the same that is done in differential equations in different cases...

Comment: @Netchaiev You should study more math and get familiar with Leibniz notation and the chain rule. There is nothing wrong, or even ambiguous with this proof.

Comment: What is the formal definition of the "symbol" $\frac{df}{dg}$?

Comment: The understanding is not the problem, the problem is that, you can't use $du/dv$ as a fraction (excepted in Physics...) $du$ is a differential linear form of order one... you can't divide it/ multiply as if it were floats... It is everything except a correct proof.

Comment: @orole: you need to study a bit more too the correct definition of differential linear forms... We are not talking about notation here, but about the validity of the proof...

Comment: @Netchaiev That proof is perfectly valid. Actually, it is one manifestation of the beauty why calculus is called calculus, the genius of Leibniz. You are imagining there is something wrong with it only because you don't understand it. So, go study the chain rule. By the way, there is not a single differential form in all of this page. So, study also what is a differential form.

Comment: a trick with notations is not a proof. The chain rule underneath doesn't justify any abuse of notation. So, go and learn what IS $df$. Good luck.

Comment: @Netchaiev It is funny how the answer that you posted, and then deleted it is exactly this one written with a different notation. "tricks with notation", eh? That is the damage that some teachers do spooking students about Leibniz's notation.

Comment: @Netchaiev If only I were not tenured and taught this from time to time for a living. Look again in this whole page, there is not a single $df$, not a single differential, in any answer. You do not understand Leibniz notation. Every step in this answer talks about properties about derivatives, just like the proof that you wrote and deleted it. Exactly the same thing that you wrote, just using Leibniz's notation. All your ranting is because you don't know Leibniz notation.

Comment: @orole: fine, I guess you understand Leibniz notations (he had to invent something besides Newton, though...) while I understand mathematics... I'm sure you win.

Comment: @Netchaiev I don't win anything. It is more like you are the one that has a lost because you are refusing to learn. Anyway, all you need to do is realize that if you have a concern about this proof, the same concern would apply to yours, since they are exactly the same proof.

Comment: @Netchaiev Just so you know, the spooky thing that some teacher of yours frightened you about is $df=\frac{df}{dx}dx$, in which similarly looking notation is representing objects of different nature. Nothing like that is being used here. Not that it would be wrong either, if it were.

Comment: Well, I guess the problem occured because I claimed $\frac{dx}{d(1-x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{d(1-x)}{dx}}$ because it is as same as considering differentials as fractions (I think this is where the problem occurs because one step before that is simply a result of Chain Rule). But without doing that, we could've define $u = 1-x$. Then $\frac{dx}{d(1-x)} = \frac{d(1-u)}{du} = -1$. I hope I didn't misundestand your point again.

Comment: @ArsenBerk And that step is derivative of the inverse, which is also due to the chain rule. It is just that people remember being scared about Leibniz but often times don't remember exactly what is it what they are supposed to be scared about.

Comment: @orole: you are just showing how unadapted and sloppy the Leibniz notations are... I perfectly understand them - as a trick of notation - but using them as a proof it is certainly the best way to make beginners all wrong. Nowhere $dy/d(1-x)$ is defined... so good luck for them to understand what it is. In the other hand, you have a function of one variable, you can defined what is a derivative and you can play with composition and chain rule. Again, here it is a bad trick with dirty notations hiding the theorems behind: it is difficult to see the point, but we understood, you like it very much

Comment: @ArsenBerk: Yes, I know that, as a notation, it is possible to justify it; but to do so, you finally had to defined a composition and apply the chain rule... without that step it wasn't a proof (that's just what I said), with it, it becomes one, but again, I fail to see what the notation brought besides a possible misunderstanding about a "magical" simplification at some point. Not scared from some teachers, but concerned of the true understanding of the students.

Comment: this can be justified formally using the notions of Daniell of differentiation respect to a function

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function of $1-x$ and you want to differentiate that function with respect to $1-x$, start by setting $y:= 1 - x$.  Then replace every $1-x$ with $y$ in the expression, and differentiate the expression with respect to the variable $y$.  After differentiating, replace each of the $y$'s in the derivative with $1-x$.

For example, to differentiate $(1 - x)^{2}$ with respect to $1-x$, set $y := 1 - x$, and so the expression is now $y^{2}$.  Differentiating this with respect to $y$ gives $2y$, and substituting $1-x$ back in gives the derivative as $2(1-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ArsenBerk generally, but I think there is in fact an even easier way.  If you view the differential *itself* as an operator, then the operation is even easier.  Rather than thinking about *derivatives*, you can think of the differential $d()$ as being an operator in and of itself, and the derivative as simply being a ratio of differentials.  So, for instance, $d(x^2) = 2x\,dx$ and $d(xy) = x\,dy + y\,dx$ and so forth.  So, in this case, you have:

$$\frac{dy}{d(1 - x)}$$

The numerator is already simplified, we just have to apply the differential to the denominator.  Using the addition rule, $d(1 - x) = d(1) - d(x)$.  The differential of a constant is zero, and the differential of $x$ is just $dx$ by definition.  Therefore, $d(1 - x) = -dx$.  Therefore, you can very simply state:

$$\frac{dy}{d(1 - x)} = \frac{dy}{d(1) - d(x)} = \frac{dy}{0 - dx} = -\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment: I wanted to add that the manipulation in the answer of @ArsenBerk can be justified formally using the [notion of differentiation respect to a function of limited variation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1988974?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) of Daniell.

Also we can read the article of Pouso and Rodriguez [A New Unification of Continuous, Discrete, and Impulsive Calculus through Stieltjes Derivatives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277952939_A_New_Unification_of_Continuous_Discrete_and_Impulsive_Calculus_through_Stieltjes_Derivatives) for an amazing generalization of this idea.

Following the last cited article we would have something like: let $f,g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ and $g$ monotone and left (or right) continuous, then we can define the derivative of $f$ at $x$ with respect to $g$ as
$$
f'_g(x):=\begin{cases}
\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{g(t)-g(x)},\quad \text{ if }g\text{ is continuous at }x\\
\lim_{t\to x^+}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{g(t)-g(x)},\quad \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
if the corresponding limit exists (the lateral limit is the other if we choose $g$ right continuous instead of left continuous).

This $g$-derivative defines the Radon-Nikodym derivative of a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure defined by $f$ (when this is possible) respect to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure defined by $g$ (when $df\ll dg$, of course), and a more general result can be found in the context of the Kurzweil-Stieltjes integration.

Therefore when $f$ and $g$ are normally differentiable at $x$, and $g'(x)\neq 0$, we have that $f'_g(x)=f'(x)/g'(x)$, what is the same result obtained by @ArsenBerk and his "heuristic" (maybe esoteric?) manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late to go for it but... nah.
Here is a simpler question that you might be asking:

Find $\frac{d}{dt}(3t^2 + 3)$ and $\frac{d}{d(1-t)}(3t^2 + 3)$
Too solve this question, we can use the rule of parametric differentiation. Simply put: we can write $y$ as $y = 3x^2+3$ and $x$ as $x = t$  & $x=1-t$. When performing the parametric differentiation: $$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}(3t^2+3) }{\frac{dx}{dt} (t)}$$ Similarly:
$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}(3t^2+3) }{\frac{dx}{dt} (1-t)}$$
Solving the derivative, we get (for $x = t$ and $1-t$ respectively):
$$\frac{6t}{1} = 6t$$
and
$$\frac{6t}{-1} = -6t$$
Hope this helps!